# How to get hidden value using template querySelectorAll

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, lightning

I have a lightning-record-edit-form in a for loop that contains some input values. I'm retrieving their default values from Apex. One of the values I get from Apex is a lookup, and I don't want it to be displayed in the UI.

Therefore, I have hidden that value in the lightning-record-edit-form. However, when I use the template querySelectorAll in my JavaScript, I'm not able to retrieve that value.

**HTML:**

```
<template for:each={prodCompensationList} for:item="item" for:index="index">
            <lightning-record-edit-form key={item.Id} object-api-name="Compensation_Product__c" class="slds-m-bottom_medium my-form">
                <lightning-messages> </lightning-messages>
                
                    <lightning-layout-item size="12" padding="around-small">
                        <lightning-input-field field-name="Product__c" variant="label-stacked" value={item.Product__c} required>
                        </lightning-input-field>
                    </lightning-layout-item>
                    <lightning-layout-item size="12" padding="around-small">
                        <lightning-input-field field-name="Quantity__c" variant="label-stacked" value={item.Quantity__c} required>
                        </lightning-input-field>
                    </lightning-layout-item>
                    <lightning-layout-item size="12" padding="around-small">
                        <lightning-input-field field-name="Double_Commission__c" variant="label-stacked" value={item.Double_Commission__c} >
                        </lightning-input-field>
                    </lightning-layout-item>

<!-- This is hidden field **Product_Commission_Rate__c** -->
                    <lightning-layout-item size="12" padding="around-small">
                        <lightning-input-field field-name="Product_Commission_Rate__c" variant="label-stacked" value={item.Product_Commission_Rate__c} >
                        </lightning-input-field>
                    </lightning-layout-item>
            </lightning-record-edit-form>
        </template>
```

**JS:**

```
const forms = Array.from(this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-record-edit-form'));
              console.log('>>> forms... '+JSON.stringify(forms));
            const records = forms.map((form) => {
            const fields = Array.from(form.querySelectorAll('lightning-input-field'));
            const fieldData = fields.map((field) => [field.fieldName, field.value]);
                return Object.fromEntries([['sobjectType', 'Compensation_Product__c'], ...fieldData]);
            });
```

Comment: If you use `slds-hide` then the field will still be in the DOM and `querySelectorAll('lightning-input-field')` should match it. In your code I don't see anything that hides the field?

Comment: @KeithC thanks it worked, earlier I was using slds-hidden instead of slds-hide

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are not able to retrieve the hidden value from the [`lightning-record-edit-form`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-edit-form) using the template **querySelectorAll** is that the hidden attribute or CSS style prevents the element from being rendered in the DOM. Therefore, the **querySelectorAll** method cannot find the element and returns an empty list.

To solve this issue, you can use one of the following methods:

- Use the `data-*` attribute instead of the hidden attribute or CSS style to hide the element. The `data-*` attribute allows you to store custom data on an element without affecting its rendering.

  - For example, you can use something like this in your HTML template: `<lightning-input-field field-name="LookupField__c" data-hidden="true"></lightning-input-field>`
  - And then use something like this in your JavaScript file:`let hiddenValue = this.template.querySelectorAll('[data-hidden="true"]');`
- Use the `aria-hidden` attribute instead of the hidden attribute or CSS style to hide the element. The `aria-hidden` attribute indicates that the element is not visible or interactive, but it still exists in the DOM.

  - For example, you can use something like this in your HTML template:`<lightning-input-field field-name="LookupField__c" aria-hidden="true"></lightning-input-field>`
  - And then use something like this in your JavaScript file:`let hiddenValue = this.template.querySelectorAll('[aria-hidden="true"]');`